# How to setup a Google Apps GTalk account in Pidgin?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, pidgin

I can setup my normal GTalk account in Pidgin, but I don't know how to do it with my work GTalk which is for a Google Apps domain.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

http://www.answerbag.com/question_will-pidgin-work-with-google-talk-if-your-using-your-own-domain-name-with-gmail-through-google-apps_396552/

1. You have to change the advanced options of the account.
2. Check box for "Force old SSL..."
3. Set "Port" to 443 (if 443 doesn't work, try 5223)
4. Set "Server" to talk.google.com

http://www.itech7.com/HOWTO/Configure-GTalkGmail-Account-on-Pidgin

Comment: Haha, asked the question, then used the http://lmgtfy.com/ web site to find the answer?  ;)

Comment: @JMD exactly, it's my contribution for the community

Comment: Why third party blog links ? Google's Support page mentions it.
http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=49147

Comment: Sathya: This answer was the only one that enabled my Work GTalk on Pidgin after searching wildly on the internet. The key was to use 'Use old style SSL' and to set the port to '443'. This isn't mentioned in Google's support page.

Comment: @runaros what version of pidgin?

Comment: @EvanCarroll I don't work there anymore, so I'm not sure. But it was almost certainly the newest version at the time of writing (March 2012).

Answer (score 10):

From the [Official Article: Configure Pidgin to connect to Google Talk](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=49147) (with modifications by me):

Once you download Pidgin, you'll need to configure your client to connect to the Google Talk service.

To configure your account:

1. Open Pidgin.
2. Select *Add* (under Accounts → Manage Accounts → Add)

Enter the following information in the *Add Account* window:

> **Protocol:** XMPP
>
> **Screen Name:** your Google Talk username without any @ symbol or domain *content to the left of the '@' symbol).
>
> **Server: (or Domain)** Enter the portion of your email address after the @ symbol. For example, gordon@example.com will enter example.com as the server value. (If you're not a Google Apps for Your Domain user, please visit the Google Talk Help Center for instructions.)
>   Password: we suggest leaving this field blank for increased security, but if you'd like to log in automatically, enter your password
>
> **Local Alias:** leave this field blank
>
> **Remember password:** check the box if you'd like Pidgin to remember your password (you won't be prompted to enter it each time you log in, if you select this option)
>
> **New mail notifications:** check the box if you'd like Pidgin to notify you of unread email in your inbox.

Finally,

1. Click the *'Advanced'* tab and select *Require SSL/TLS*, or sometimes more simply *Require Encryption*.
2. Google doesn't say this, but **make sure under "Connect Server:" that *talk.google.com.* is set**.
3. Click *Save*.

You're now ready to connect to the Google Talk service using Pidgin.

Answer (score 1):

An updated answer:
Let's say user is myname@xyz.com
Setup a Gtalk account with the following details:
User:       myname
Domain:     xyz.com
Resource:   gmail.com
Password:   ********     (enter your password here)

Then click on advanced and the only change to the defaults is the connect server:

Connect Server:  talk.google.com

You should be set now.

I tried this and it worked for me. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/RWb8R-vg_qM has more details.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to have your /etc/hostname in your /etc/hosts.

I mean :
if /etc/hostname contains `julien` you need a 
`127.0.0.1 localhost julien` in your /etc/hosts.

Comment: How on earth is this related? :P

Comment: Don't remember exactly, but my pidgin won't connect to gtalk without this. I may try removing it to check why.

Answer (score 0):

This has changed. We need to set app-specific password. Just follow instructions at http://mylinuxbook.com/how-to-get-pidgin-working-with-gtalk/

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

This is a newer method that sure works:

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/37752-using-pidgin-with-a-google-apps-domain

But remember to use an application password if you have 2-step verification.

Comment: Consider adding some quoted reference to this answer supporting what you state in case the link ever dies so the answer content is still available that is currently only available via that link per your suggestion.