# How to associate gmail id to pidgin account

Tags: instant-messaging, pidgin, google-talk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to setup a Google Apps GTalk account in Pidgin?](https://superuser.com/questions/51327/how-to-setup-a-google-apps-gtalk-account-in-pidgin)

I have an id (myname@mycompany.com) registered via Google Apps so I use myname@mycompany.com to register in Google Talk. How do I do the same via pidgin?

Comment: Have you tried Google's help system? It's usually fairly good for things like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a detail help from Google . Check [this](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=49147) out