# How to use MCabber (a Jabber client) with Google Enterprise Account?

Tags: google-talk, google-workspace, jabber, xmpp

My company has signed up with Google Apps for Business so I have a Gmail address of the form myname@mycompany.com.

I use MCabber as a chat client and am unable to connect using my working `mcabberrc` file (which works with my @gmail.com account) with the JID set to the company email address.

I have tried several different configuration settings related to SSL and setting the server/port, but the more research I do, the more it seems it should not be necessary (just setting the JID is expected to work).

With the default `mcabberrc`, MCabber reports:

```
01-20 21:36:08  Connecting to server

01-20 21:36:08   with resource mcabber.c387d12b
```

Comment: I figured it out, but stackexchange says I don't have enough karma to answer my own question. My well written answer is going in the garbage. FYI: Set the server=talk.google.com, port=5223, and enable ssl and disable tls, and set ssl_ignore_checks=1.

Comment: The message should have told you you needed to wait 8 hours. Which means you can post your answer now. Would be great if you could do that! Thanks!

Comment: Aaaw, that's too bad. Here's some rep; please come back and post the complete answer as soon as you can, I'd really like to read it!

Comment: Overriding the server field should not be necessary if your network administrator add the requisite SRV records to your domain's DNS entries. See e.g. https://kingant.net/check_xmpp_dns/?h=jabber.org

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup a Google Apps GTalk account in Pidgin?](http://superuser.com/questions/51327/how-to-setup-a-google-apps-gtalk-account-in-pidgin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copying the End User's answer that worked. I confirmed the same problem previously and compared my settings. This worked.

FYI: Set the server=talk.google.com, port=5223, and enable ssl and disable tls, and set ssl_ignore_checks=1